# Quantity for each item select to be posted and written to a mysql database table

Tags: php, arrays, post, foreach, while-loop

$disabled in the below code repeatedly gets overwritten for example:

- Item 1 = Quantity 3 Check box = True
- Item 2 = Quantity 5 Check box = True
- Item 3 = Quantity 1 Check box = False

The values written to the table will be:

- Item 1 = Quantity 1
- Item 2 = Quantity 1
- Item 3 = Quantity 1

For the quantity I reuse an input field with the name Quantity. So in the first instance I setting Quantity = 3 then I set Quantity to 7 and finally to 5.

As the input fields all have the same name (and the Quantity is not an array), the $_POST ['Quantity'] can only hold one value, the last one

I think I have the answer though - I need to use the variable Addbox[] to store which item id you are adding - I could use the same variable to store the quantity as well. This would create consecutive pairs of values Addbox[0] would contain ItemID, Addbox[1] would contain Quantity. and so on or store quantity in an array: Quantity[] - and process as for Addbox[]

Problem is I cannot successfully edit my code to achieve the above.

```
//-----------------------THIS IS WHERE THE ITEMS ARE DISPLAYED

    if (isset ($_POST['BrowseItem'])){


    if (isset ($_SESSION['Username'])) {

$disabled = "";

}
else {
$disabled = "disabled";
}

?>
</form>
<form id="Searchform" name="Searchform" method="post">
<div id="WishlistDiv">
<?php


    echo "<table width='705' border='1' > <tr> <th>Item Name</th> <th>Item Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Image</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";


  //-create  while loop and loop through result set 
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($allresult)){ 
              $Itemname =$row['Item_Name']; 
              $Itemdesc =$row['Item_Description']; 
              $ItemID =$row['Item_ID']; 
              $Price =$row['Price'];
              $Image =$row['Image'];
      //-display the result of the array in a table


      echo "<tr> <td> <a  href=\"ManageWishlist.php? id=$ItemID\">"   .$Itemname . "</td>";

      echo "<td>" . $Itemdesc . "</td>";

      echo "<td>" . $Price . "</td>";

      echo "<td> <img src =". $Image ." height=70px> </td>";

     $i = 1;   

      if (isset ($_SESSION['Username'])){



      echo "<td> <select name='Quantity' />";

      // while loop to enable user to select the quantity they want
      while ($i<=10) {
      echo "<option value=\"" . $i . "\">" . $i . "</option>";

      $i++;
      }

      echo "</select> </td>";

      echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='Addbox[]' value='".$row['Item_ID']."'/> </td>";
    }
        else {

        echo "<td> <select name='Quantity' />value='" 

.$i."'  </select> </td>";
        echo "<td> Please log in to add this item to your wishlist</td>";

        }

      }
      echo "</table>";

      echo "<input type='Submit' name='Add' id='Add' value='Add selected to Wishlist' action='ReturnResult.php' $disabled/> ";

  }
  }
  ?>
  </p>
</form>
</div>


//---------------------------------------THIS IS THE END OF THE TABLE
```

This is the for each row loop

```
if (isset ($_POST['Addbox'])) {
$items = $_POST['Addbox'];


foreach ($items as &$itemid){

    $quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];

    echo $quantity;

if ($itemid > 0){


$sql = "INSERT INTO 
        `wishlist` (`User_ID`, 
                    `Product_ID`, 
                    `Quantity`) 
        VALUES ($userid, $itemid, $quantity)";

mysql_query($sql);

}
```

Comment: we need debug intermediary informations.

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end, the select box needed to be as such:

```
<td> <select name="quantity[]">

$i = 1;

while ($i <=10) {

       option value=\"" . $i . "\"">" . $i . "</option>";

       $i++

      }

echo "</select></td>";
```

The if (isset()) statement then needed to be:

```
$count = count ($_POST['Addbox']);

$sql "INSERT INTO `wishlist` (`User_ID`, `Product_ID`, `Quantity`) VALUES ";


for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

   $item = $_POST['Addbox'][$i];
   $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$i];

 $sql .= ($userid, $item, $quantity); 

  if ($i !== $count-1){

       $sql .= ", ";

   }
  }

   mysql_query($sql);
 }
```